# Authoritative SQL standard documentation

Tags: sql

I'm curious to know some more details about the various SQL standard's, i.e. `SQL-92`, `SQL:99`, `SQL:2003`, `SQL:2008` etc. There is a short and useful overview on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2008), with links to very expensive documents. Why are those documents not open to public? Can I find some open and free information?

Please, don't post links you found from Google. I'm interested in somewhat authoritative documentation only.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quoting from [one of my web sites](https://modern-sql.com/standard):

> We all love open source software. Wouldn’t it be great if
> international standard documents such as the SQL standard would be
> open too?
>
> As a matter of fact: they are!
>
> However, they are not free—just public. Very much like open source
> software is not necessarily free. Too often, we neglect these
> differences. Just because we have to pay for the standard doesn't mean
> it is secret.
>
> A download of the most relevant part of the SQL standard—part 2—is
> available for [USD 60 at ANSI](http://webstore.ansi.org/RecordDetail.aspx?sku=INCITS%2FISO%2FIEC%209075-2%3A2011%20%5B2012%5D). A CD with all parts on it can be bought
> from ISO for CHF 352. Not free, but affordable.

You mentioned in some comments that you are mostly interested in part 2, so spending USD 60 might be your best option.

If you just need to know about the syntax up to 2003, there are two great free resources:

- BNF grammar of SQL-92, SQL:1999 and SQL:2003: http://www.savage.net.au/SQL/
- Online validator for SQL:1999: https://developer.mimer.com/services/sql-validator-99/

Finally, the complete text of [“SQL-99 Complete, Really” is available at the MariaDB knowledge base](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-99/). However, this book was written in 1999 when no database actually supported the described features. Keep that in mind when using this resource.

Other answers also mentioned "free" copies of the standards available on the web. Yes there are—those are mostly draft versions. I can't tell which of them are legal, so I rather not link them.

Finally a little self ad: I've just launched http://modern-sql.com/ to explain the standard in an easily accessible way to developers. Note that the actual standards text is written like laws are written :) Depending on your background, that might anyway not what you want.

Answer (score 7):

The Postgresql Developer FAQ maintains links to each of them:

http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Developer_FAQ#Where_can_I_get_a_copy_of_the_SQL_standards.3F

Answer (score 2):

There are some hyperlinked versions of 92, 99 and 2003 [here](http://savage.net.au/SQL/)

However, I've never been able to use them effectively (read: I gave up).

This [92 text is useful](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) (and is quoted here on SO several times)

Answer (score 2):

ISO/IEC 9075-1:2011 -- google that.

Actually, digging around I found

http://www.incits.org/standards-information/
and it has freely availble section that clicks to something that redirects to here:
http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/index.html

And finally the standards.

You have to accept a license agreement to download a pdf.

However, from what I have read in my pursuit  - the RDMS well the 'RD' part is going the way of the dinosaur..  If you are building something new (therefore want the new standards) you may want to reconsider all options.

Comment: The SQL/Framework document is not the interesting part of the standard. The SQL/Foundation document is. How you came to conclude with the dinosaur analogy, however, might be a different story

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to pay for *all* of the standards.  [SQL-92](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) is freely available, for instance.

Comment: Thanks, that's very interesting. Do you know why the more advanced standards don't seem to be available for free? I'm really curious about the exact definition for window functions (from SQL:2003), for instance.

Comment: @Lukas: Unfortunately, many organizations still live in the previous millenium, charging money for something that cleary should be free (since freely available standards is beneficial to society).  I don't have a clue why they charge such high amounts of money for making copies of ones of zeroes.

Comment: @Lukas: By the way, check this out https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/ISO#ISO_document_copyright -- it says you can get drafts for free (with the caveat that they might be different from the final standards).  I'd like to see an income report from ISO, because I refuse to believe they need the money from selling the standards docs.  It should be fully subsidized by member countries.

Comment: Who knows... These things may be precisely the reasons why the "RDBMS-community" has failed so far to bring up an RDBMS that actually implements the standard and only the standard, because proprietary "extensions" have always been better. But I'm quite happy with Denis' link to the Postgres site. Have you seen it?