# Is the JDBC ResultSet an application-level query cursor

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, database-cursor

The [database cursor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursor_%28databases%29) definition is strikingly resembling with the JDBC *ResultSet* API.

- the database cursor can be forward-only just like [ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY).
- the database cursor can be scrollable and even have a sensitivity setting just like [ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE).
- there is also support for holdability like [ResultSet.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT)
- and even the support for positional update/delete is being replicated into JDBC [ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#CONCUR_UPDATABLE)

But in spite of all these resembling, [MySQL doesn't support database cursors](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html):

> MySQL does not support SQL cursors, and the JDBC driver doesn't
>   emulate them, so setCursorName() has no effect.

So, is the JDBC implementation a data access specification that mimics a database cursor implementation, even if the database doesn't really support such a feature?

Comment: I think JDBC had not built for specific database. It provide general  functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can certainly think of it that way. All of these concepts are inherited from ODBC so you can thank (blame?) history for things being this way. Cursors aren't widely supported by most dbs to the full extent that features are provided in APIs such as JDBC. In MySQL specifically, there is a cursor "fetch" supported as of MySQL 5.0 which means that the driver isn't forced to read the entire result, whether it's needed or not. This means that it is possible to abandon a result set early with little to no cost. However, an additional round-trip is required to request blocks of rows periodically. MySQL Connector/J doesn't enforce the FORWARD_ONLY semantics by default and buffers the entire result in the client allowing "scrollability". However, due to the implementation in the server, this does not allow for being sensitive to changes committed in other transactions. Features are typically mimicked/emulated where possible to provide the convenience of the API.

Answer (score 8):

What's in a name...

Indeed, a `ResultSet` and a database cursor are semantically similar. [The SQL:2011 standard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6000847/521799) specifies:

> A cursor is a mechanism by which the rows of a table may be acted on (e.g., returned to a host programming language) one at a time.

That does sound a lot like a `ResultSet`. Further down, the SQL:2011 standard goes on and mentions:

> A cursor declaration descriptor and a result set descriptor have four properties: the sensitivity property (either SENSITIVE, INSENSITIVE, or ASENSITIVE), the scrollability property (either SCROLL or NO SCROLL), the holdability property (either WITH HOLD or WITHOUT HOLD), and the returnability property (either WITH RETURN or WITHOUT RETURN).

In other words, none of these features were "invented" by the JDBC (or ODBC) spec teams. They do exist exactly in this form in many SQL database implementations, and as with any specs, many of the above features are optional in SQL implementations as well.

You've gotten an authoritative response on the MySQL part already by [Jess](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32644927/521799). I'd like to add that JDBC, like any specification on a high level, has parts that are required and parts that are optional.

Looking at the [JDBC Spec](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jdbc-4_2-mrel2-eval-spec/index.html), I can see the following relevant parts.

> #### 6.3 JDBC 4.2 API Compliance
>
> A driver that is compliant with the JDBC specification must do the following:
>
> [...]
>
> It must implement the Statement interface with the exception of the following
>   optional methods:
>
> - [...]
> - setCursorName
> - [...]
>
> It must implement the ResultSet interface with the exception of the following
>   optional methods:
>
> - [...]
> - getCursorName
> - [...]

The same is true for the implementation of `ResultSet` types. Further down in the specs, you will find:

> The method `DatabaseMetaData.supportsResultSetType` returns `true` if the
>   specified type is supported by the driver and `false` otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding about JDBC ResultSet i will say it does not depends Database which it connects, its behaviour would be same.

JDBC will always fetches default number of rows (not the entire result set) to your local memory. Once you reach at the last line of the fetched rows (say by doing next() and try to access next row) and if there are more rows in the result, then another round-trip call will be made to the database to fetch next batch of rows to local memory.

Even you can set number of rows you want fetch in local memory than usual, you may consider CachedRowSet.

When you set the fetchSize() on the Statement, you are only giving a instruction to the JDBC driver how much you want it should fetch, but JDBC driver is free to ignore your instructions. I do not know what the Oracle driver does with the fetchSize(). Most of times its observed that MySQL JDBC driver will always fetch all rows unless you set the fetchSize() to Integer.MIN_VALUE.